# Relation between Hermite interpolation and Bezier curve

Tags: numerical-methods, bezier-curve

I will really appreciate if someone can explain me the relation between Hermite interpolation and Bezier Curve. For example, $p(0)=1,p(3)=2,p'(0)=1,p'(3)=1$, how do we do the Hermite interpolation? And from the Hermite interpolation how should we draw the Bezier polygon(control polygon) and the Bezier curves?And how should we apply Casteljau algorithm to evaluate the Bezier curve at $u=1,u=2$?

Overall, I really want to know the relation between Bezier curve and Hermite interpolation.

Really hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: "how do we do the Hermite interpolation?" - a general cubic looks like $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ with derivative $3ax^2+2bx+c$. You can substitute your four conditions to yield a linear system in four unknowns, which can then be solved with the usual methods. The resulting polynomial is your Hermite interpolant.

Comment: En, do you know how to get the cubic Hermite interpolant by using Hermite polynomial basis on any interval [a,b]?

Comment: I do, but I always have to look up the Hermite basis functions since I haven't memorized them; that's why I prefer the mechanical method. Both methods should yield the same polynomial anyway when all is said and done.